# Table indexed well but query taking long time to execute?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

> one of our query is scanning full table and it was taking around
>   15mins and it was impacted on our application performance. The table
>   having proper indexes but it was scanning complete table. How to
>   rewrite or is there any best way indexing?

Query:

```
 select count(u.user_id) 
   from iflora_user_newsletter_map unm, 
        users u , 
        addresses a 
  where unm.user_id=u.user_id 
    and unm.newsletter_id=1 
    and unm.active=1  
    and u.user_id=a.user_id 
    and a.type='billing';\
```

Explain Plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref                  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | unm   | ref  | idx_2243,idx_747 | idx_2243 | 4       | const                | 2960628 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref  | idx_747          | idx_747  | 5       | shopcart.unm.user_id |       1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | idx_747          | idx_747  | 4       | shopcart.unm.user_id |       1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Tables structure:

```
mysql> show create table iflora_user_newsletter_map\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: iflora_user_newsletter_map
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `iflora_user_newsletter_map` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `newsletter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_subscribed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_unsubscribed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_preference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_preference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_preference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_preference` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_2243` (`newsletter_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_1571` (`date_subscribed`),
  KEY `idx_1798` (`date_unsubscribed`),
  KEY `idx_747` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(12) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_visit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_since` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transient` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_address_id` decimal(12,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt_in_email` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt_in_email2` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt_in_email3` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_promotions` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `textonly_email` char(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `express_checkout` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `webstore_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_747` (`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_417` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_delete_transient` (`transient`,`last_visit`),
  KEY `users_n1` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table addresses\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: addresses
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_id` decimal(12,0) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_phone` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_phone_ext` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `evening_phone` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_phone` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_name` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `personal_notes` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `complete_flag` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT 'N',
  `credit_card_number` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_type` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_exp_month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_exp_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address2` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_type` varchar(1) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_type` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_day` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_month` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_year` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `skip_queries` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_qas_results` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qas_queried` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debit_card_issue_number` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_start_year` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_start_month` varchar(4) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_the_name_of` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameters` varchar(1024) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_1042` (`address_id`),
  KEY `idx_747` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

@morilo,

here is explain after adding the index 
create index idx_748 on iflora_user_newsletter_map(user_id,newsletter_id,active);

explain Plan

```
mysql> explain select count(u.user_id) from iflora_user_newsletter_map unm, users u , addresses a where unm.user_id=u.user_id and unm.newsletter_id=1  and unm.active=1  and u.user_id=a.user_id and a.type='billing';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                     | key      | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | index  | idx_747                           | idx_747  | 5       | NULL                     | 2575 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | idx_747,idx_ads                   | idx_747  | 4       | shopcart.u.user_id       |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | unm   | eq_ref | idx_2243,idx_news,idx_747,idx_748 | idx_2243 | 8       | const,shopcart.u.user_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Explain Plan use force index

mysql> explain select count(u.user_id) from iflora_user_newsletter_map unm, users u , addresses a where unm.user_id=u.user_id and unm.newsletter_id=1  and unm.active=1  and u.user_id=a.user_id and a.type='billing';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                     | key      | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | index  | idx_747                           | idx_747  | 5       | NULL                     | 2575 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | idx_747,idx_ads                   | idx_747  | 4       | shopcart.u.user_id       |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | unm   | eq_ref | idx_2243,idx_news,idx_747,idx_748 | idx_2243 | 8       | const,shopcart.u.user_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: could you try to add an combined index on iflora_user_newsletter_map wht the columns user_id,newsletter_id,active and see if the execution plan changes?

Comment: Side Note : Use explicit join instead of implicit.

Comment: created composite index as you mentioned but no change in explain plan.

Comment: Every row in your explain plan shows usage of a key. Where is the table scan?

Answer (score 2):

The select is scanning all the rows because of the conditions "unm.newsletter_id=1  and unm.active=1": those fields are not indexed and therefore, the engine has to scan all rows.
include those fields too in the index 'user_id' to solve the problem.
I recommend changing:
    KEY `idx_747` (`user_id`)
To
    KEY `idx_747` (`user_id`,`newsletter_id`,`active`)

Comment: This answer would be slightly better if you showed the index you're suggesting and explained a little better.

Comment: As per your suggession i was added index idx_747 (user_id,newsletter_id,active) number of rows scan got increased ,looks like no change in explain plan and query performance.

Comment: Can you paste the new explain to see the indexes used? You may need to "force index ´idx_747´" in the query

Answer (score 2):

This is your query written with proper join syntax:

```
select count(u.user_id)
from iflora_user_newsletter_map unm join
     users u 
     on unm.user_id = u.user_id join
     addresses a
     on u.user_id = a.user_id 
where unm.newsletter_id = 1  and unm.active = 1 and a.type = 'billing';
```

This query would potentially benefit from the following indexes:

```
addresses(user_id, type)
iflora_user_newsletter_map(newsletter_id, active, user_id)
```

or:

```
addresses(type, user_id)
iflora_user_newsletter_map(active, user_id, newsletter_id)
```

I do not see the columns in the `where` clause in the indexes in your table.  Which of these is better depends on how much data in each table is being used for the indexes.  The larger table appears to be `unm`, so I would try the first set of indexes first.